# how to remove these loops in python for sigmoid function

Tags: python, numpy, sigmoid

```
def sigmoid(a):
    g = a
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            if a[i][j] >= 0:
                z = np.exp(-a[i][j])
                g[i][j] = 1 / (1 + z)
            else:
                z = np.exp(a[i][j])
                g[i][j] = 1 / (1 + z)
    return g
```

how can I improve this code? these loops are taking too much time.
I tried the following code

```
def sigmoid(a):
    if a > 0:
       z = np.exp(-a)
       return 1/(1+z)
    else:
       z = np.exp(a)
       return 1/(1+z)
```

But its not working for a 2D array or even 1D array, gives error on if statement.

```
if a > 0: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Your second function seems to be working fine for me with a single input. Are you trying to pass an array as an argument?

Comment: For second `def sigmoid(a)`  you;re giving array and comparing it with single number. You should try: `a[i] > 0` ...

Comment: @IshwarVenugopal yes I am passing a 2d array as an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`abs(a)` gives the absolute value of each element in a `numpy` array, so you can simply use that:

```
def sigmoid(a):
    z = np.exp(-abs(a))
    return 1/(1+z)
```

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer in that case.